# What is the best way to create a simple responsive html page with one centered image

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I want to create a simple index page for a website with one image. The only thing I want is that the image is centered (width 1000px) and that it is responsive, so that it gets smaller when the window is smaller.

I would like to see the the html5 en css structure if possible.

Thank you!

Here's the site: theduckvariations.be

Comment: Simply use a table with width and max-width. Done

Comment: @Andi why a `table`?

Comment: no css needed. And a table with a % width does rescaling. If you like you could use a div block with those settings to. But a table rescales the containing image.

Comment: [*Anything* with a % width does rescaling](http://jsfiddle.net/j1ec55am/). Using a table just for that would be silly.

Answer (score 0):

try using % in place of 1000px in `.wrapper` class...Is this u needed ??

```
.wrapper {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Hi aashi, that works! But now the image is wider than the original size of 1000px. If I set the content-main class to 1000px width, the image isn't centered anymore...